# HBox children on top without changing layout order

Tags: javafx

I have created a Hbox with several Buttons inside as children. I want to increase one button size and be on top of others. Not as appreciated in the figure... I Have tried with `children_button.toFront()` but it changes the layout order.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this works in an Hbox as I think toFront puts the Child on the first position of the ChildList in the parent Node. But this would mean that HBox would layout it on the very left on first place. So maybe they are overriding the default behavior in this Case? Just my guess

Comment: That sounds right. Try a `GridPane` with a single row instead.

Comment: Thanks!! As @James_D suggested it works using a GridPane with a single row.